# Nginx location image

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, rewrite, изображения

Есть папка с картинками `site.com/upload/image1.png` и я не могу добавить правило если по запросу картинки из папки `upload` нет, то выдать картинку (по умолчанию `noimage.png`) без изменения url

Пытался так №1:

```
location /upload/ {
    try_files $uri /1_image_not_found.png;
}
```

Пытался так №2:

```
location /upload/ {
    error_page 404 /1_image_not_found.png;
}
```

Толку ноль вижу страницу 404

UPD:
Полностью конфиг
UPD2: Изменил

```
server {
listen 443 ssl spdy;
server_name site.com www.site.com;
resolver 8.8.8.8;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.com.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

root /home/site.com/public_html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

access_log /dev/null;
error_log /home/site.com/logs/nginx.error.log;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location ~* ".+\.(?:ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|css|swf|js|atom|jpe?g|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$" {
    access_log  off;
    log_not_found   off;
    expires     max;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/site.com;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /upload/ {
    try_files $uri /upload/1_image_not_found.png;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    return 404;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /upload/ {

         try_files $uri /upload/1_image_not_found.png;
}
```

**UPD: После публикации полной конфигурации.**

Nginx обходит location в определенном порядке. Сначала он ищет совпадения среди location заданных строками, в вашем случае максимально близкий это / и /upload/, но дальше nginx ищет среди location заданных регулярными выражениями. В вашем случае это будет строка где вы указываете всю статику, чтобы выключить журналирование добавить кэширование. Именно по этой причине не срабатывает изображение по умолчанию.

Один из вариантов решения сделать *location /upload/* не строковой, а с помощью регулярных выражений. Например *location ~ ^/upload/(.+)*.

Более подробно можно прочитать в инструкции nginx: [Как nginx обрабатывает запросы](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Руслан, я вам немного поправил форматирование. Используйте Ctrl+K на блоке текста, чтобы его оформить как код.

Comment: ситуация такая же, уже и не знаю что делать (Restart и reload nginx делал)

Comment: @Ренат, у вас в сообщении написано что нужно отдать noimage.png, а в конфигурации 1_image_not_found.png. Какое изображение нужно отдать и где оно в у вас лежит.

Comment: Руслан, нужно отдать 1_image_not_found.png, лежит в upload где и все изображения

Comment: @Ренат, Предложенная мной конфигурация верная. Ищите ошибку в другом месте. Проверьте имя файла. Путь или приложите вашу конфигурацию целиком.

Comment: @Руслан Я обновил вопрос и добавил полностью конфиг. Где ошибка?(

Comment: Давайте немного приведем ваш конфиг в нормальный вид, вы где его скопировали? Замените бэкэнд на использование без if  `location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php }`. Переместите upload ниже поместив перед самым последним location, оставте только один server_name который у вас находится по середине конфигурации.

Comment: @Руслан если я правильно вас понял, я внес правки в конфиг, но ситуация пока по прежднему та же

Comment: @Ренат, Вы заинтриговали и я собрал вашу конфигурацию у себя, за исключением нескольких элементов, которых у меня на сервере нет это spdy, ssl и req_zone one. У меня все работает. У вас точно сам сервер работает и нет никаких ошибок при запуске nginx? Может есть что-то значимое в **/home/site.com/logs/nginx.error.log;**?

Comment: @Руслан Nginx 1.6.2 (ubuntu) Сервер стартует и без ошибок и все в логах ничего нет

Comment: @Руслан Если у вас остались вопросы, пожалуйста, [задайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) их _сообществу_.